# Does Application Insights Enterprise with a WPF application treat each user pc as a node

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-application-insights

We are using Application Insights to track some basic telemetry of a WPF application.  As we have developed the app we have just been using the Basic subscription, but we would like to make use of the continuous export feature which requires the Enterprise.

But according to the pricing page the Enterprise is charged at $15/node/month, will it treat each users pc as a node?  It is not really clear as AI is really aimed at web servers.

I am happy to pay for 1 node and whatever extra data charges are incurred but unsurprisingly $15 per user machine per month is not affordable.

Comment: I wonder the same thing. Maybe it is based on the public ip the telemetry comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on the role instance, so basically the machine name. You should just stick with the basic plan unless you need the OMS Connector or Continuous Export. If you have this deployed to hundreds of machines and need these features ping @DaleKoetke on twitter. I think he might even have his e-mail there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response I got from Microsoft:

What we have to understand is few things.

For assumption Node==Client

   Continuous feed to Node – We count the number of distinct nodes sending telemetry data each hour. If a node does not send any telemetry during a particular hour, then it is not counted. The monthly per-node pricing for enterprise($15)  assumes a node is sending telemetry every hour of the month, so if there are periods of inactivity for your application during the month, the actual charge will be lower.

So the short answer is yes we charge per node however the charge is proportional to the “activity feed”. No activity no charge and the enterprise charges will decline/node.

Calculation:-

So lets say you have 744 hours in a month and there is continuous feed for one node that is priced t $15.
So we see that every hour $0.020 is being charged for continuous feed/node.

You will need to calculate the continuous activity feed on the clients machine to get an idea of the charges.